# php code equivalent in asp.net vb

Tags: php, vb.net

I am working on payment system, the original code in php working fine, Now I am rewriting it on asp.net(vb), I change it step by step and stopped at this stage for different results between "php" and ".net".

**PHP CODE:**

```
$sha1Signature = "484cea8e6bd1153674548ebab5a3673a5c3d0381";

$base64Sha1Signature = base64_encode(pack("H*",$sha1Signature));

echo $base64Sha1Signature ;
```

The Result : **SEzqjmvRFTZ0VI66taNnOlw9A4E=**

**.NET CODE:**

```
    Function Pack2(strToPack As String) As Byte()
        Dim raw_bytes As Byte() = New Byte(15) {}
        For i As Integer = 0 To 32 - 1 Step 2
            raw_bytes(i / 2) = Convert.ToByte(strToPack.Substring(i, 2), 16)
        Next

        Return raw_bytes
    End Function

    Function getBase64Code(strToCode As String, Optional pack As Boolean = False) As String
        Dim byt As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strToCode)

        If pack Then
            byt = Pack2(strToCode)
        End If

        Return Convert.ToBase64String(byt)

    End Function

 Dim sha1Signature As String = "484cea8e6bd1153674548ebab5a3673a5c3d0381"

Response.Write(getBase64Code(sha1Signature, True))
```

The Result: **SEzqjmvRFTZ0VI66taNnOg==**

If you see that the results are almost the same and differ in the last 4 letters only, which means I am close to success :) The results must be identical.

PHP  : SEzqjmvRFTZ0VI66taNnOlw9A4E=

.NET : SEzqjmvRFTZ0VI66taNnOg==

Comment: why is this tagged c#?

Comment: the original was a 20-byte hash; this is a 16-byte hash (`New Byte(15)` in VB is a 16-byte array, using 0-thru-31 indices (step 2), and the base-64 length agrees: 16 bytes). Check the length of the array in the original

Comment: @BugFinder c# and vb.net very close if you find solution by c# i can convert it to vb .

Comment: "c# and vb.net very close" - them's fightin' words :)

Comment: @Realbitt thats not how SO works - we dont "find" you a solution - you need to do that.  We are here to help you work out specifics as to whats not working

Comment: @Realbitt tags are used to define what your question is regarding, a way for people who are savvy in said fields to help you. With that in mind, why not just get an answer in `vb.net` instead of `c#` then converting it to `vb.net`.

Comment: @BugFinder Excuse me English is not my native language, so you can understand what I mean here, either to find the solution or help to find the solution :).

Comment: @MarcGravell I have no experience in "php" but it is noticeable there are no array's there.

Comment: @Realbitt but again; the PHP is starting with 20 bytes of input; the .NET version is using 16. So: **why** is the .NET version using 16? what made you use that 16 byte `Pack2` method?

Comment: check the values of the pack - im guessing your pack is producing different results

Comment: Pack2 ist wrong.. It's not working like it's php-equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop should run from 0 to "input-string-length". Also the init of the bytearray should be half of your hex-string.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string tmp = "484cea8e6bd1153674548ebab5a3673a5c3d0381";

        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(Pack2(tmp)));
    }

    public static byte[] Pack2(string hexString)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2]; // two hex-digits are one byte

        for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i, 2), 16);

        return bytes;
    }
```

Comment: The code Realbit posted is not working. With this code we get the desired result "SEzqjmvRFTZ0VI66taNnOlw9A4E=". If he posts working code we could have a deeper look.

Comment: The C-share code worked fine and the result was identical, and I converted it to "VisualBasic"  The difference was in the last character. You Know, Microsoft Touches :) , anyway I put it in a compiled binary file "DLL" to use in my project.

Thanks Kara